# Ubuntu One's iPhone music app does not cache songs. How do I configure it?

Tags: ubuntu-one, iphone

I've been using the new music streaming app in my iPod Touch for a couple days now. I synced my music folder with Ubuntu One and all my music is appearing in the app. However, after playing several hours of music, the app did not cache any song to play offline. Is there a way to set how many songs are cached? When are the songs cached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current version, songs are only cached manually.  You can cache a song for offline play by tapping the circle button to the right of the song in the list.  We are considering adding automatic caching to a future version of the app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am now able to cache songs by following your suggestion. However, please, consider the possibility of, at least, cache a complete playlist, because selecting one by one the songs to be cached is a tedious affair.